# Multiple associations query - DB Modelling

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am planning a rails apps that allows a User to list one/many Vaults, at either their personal address or any other additional address (location) specified against a vault. Before I go ahead and generate the Models I want to make sure I understand what associations need to be set up between the three Models. Here the code representation that I have typed manually to depict what associations are required.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :vaults
end

class Vault < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_one :address
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database looks okay, few consideration are below :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :vaults
  has_many :addresses #(optional)if you want to fetch addresses directly
end

class Vault < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :address
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user #(optional) if you want to fetch user directly
  belongs_to :vault
end
```

Database requirement:

adresses table must contain user_id(optional) and vault_id.

vaults table must contain user_id.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, adding the other associations makes sense, thanks for the tip. I will now go ahead and create the models.